# Modern pages: impossible to set as default view anything else than grouped by author?

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, modern-experience, modern-pages, sitepages

I am not a big fan of grouping by author but trying to make "all pages" default seems impossible. Any advice?

Comment: Do you mean a List View on a List/Library? Or the SitePages library?

Comment: Are you trying to removing grouping by author or group by another column in library??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow below steps to set the **All Pages** view as default view in Site pages library:

1. Go to site pages library
2. Switch to "All Pages" view using drop down from top right corner
3. Select **Set current view as default** option from same drop down from top right corner:

   [image]

Then try navigating again to site pages library using URL like below and you will be redirected to default "All Pages" library view:

```
https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/siteName/SitePages
```

---

You can also do it from classic experience library view settings. Go to All pages view settings by selecting **Edit current view** option using drop down from top right corner.

Then you can set it as default view using below option:

[image]